# (Github) remote: Permission to username/MyProject.git denied to ($unknown_account)

Tags: git, github

```
remote: Permission to myUsername/MyProject.git denied to Dwannnn.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/joshuakimDwan/MyProject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I got this error in my terminal.

My step is:
1. git init
2. git remote add origin https://github.com/myUsername/MyProject.git
3. git add README.md
4. git commit -m "first commit"
(error) 5. git push -u origin master

when git push, I got that error. It means 'Dwannnn' cannot be permitted. But, in ~/.gitconfig, my username is not 'Dwannnn'. I don't know what the name is.

In my guess, I used account which name is 'Dwannnn' when I practiced Git using Sourcetree. So, I removed account, network data of Sourcetree. But, it doesn't work.

To sum up,
I put my Github username and useremail to my .gitconfig file, but I got message that I cannot be permitted accessing with account that I don't know about(I just can guess)

What should I do for solving that problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked for overrides in the project's own `.git/config` file?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes, I checked it a second ago. But, there is no problem...

Comment: I suspect that Sourcetree may have added a cached credential for you. What is the output of `git config --global credential.helper`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from Windows Credential Manager, and you just need delete the git account int the Windows Credential.I think it will work.

Control Panel——>User Account and family Safety——>Manage Windows Credential——>remove the github account

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error because I was accessing two accounts. This worked for me:

Go to Control Panel——>User Account and family Safety——>Manage Windows Credential——>edit GitHub account

Change the username and password according to from which acount you downloaded the code to that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a too late to answer this, but I hope it would be helpful for someone in the future.

Cause I too faced this error when trying to give an open source PR in github.

As the error says, we don't have access to directly push our code to a open source repository, we are expected to push our code through Pull Requests.

**Short answer**

- ***Fork the repository*** that you want to push the code to.
- Make changes in the fork repository.
- Push your code to remote fork.
- Give ***Pull request*** from fork repository to original repository.

**Note:** This answer is only valid if you are getting 'access denied' when trying to push to *someone else's* repository.